# Can I use Local Notification with Firebase Messaging in foreground?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to Local Notification when Firebase Messaging message data and notify in foreground?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is supposed to be done.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4Lo9u6Xgt8

Answer (score 0):

The package [local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/local_notifications) has been discontinued. As demonstrated in firebase_messaging [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart), you can use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) instead.